# Perform UICollectionView reloadData without animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios14

I have UICollectionView cells with a rounded button inside, when I perform reloadData every rounded button goes from the left to the right. To avoid it, I'm using:

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}];
```

but it doesn't seem to work anymore on iOS 14, can someone help me?

Comment: You're going to need to include more code because it's not normal for there to be an animation when reloadData is called. There must be something with how you've defined the layout of your cells or possibly something in `cell(_:forItemAt:)`.

Comment: The only thing I do is to set up texts and add event to button... In iOS 12 and 13 it's working as I expected...

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to do it:

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    [self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```